# Cannot track down the large size file/direcotry under /root

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization, rhel6

**OS**:  RHEL 6.9

**Problem**
My file system `/dev/mapper/vg_rayruhsso-lv_root` that is mounted on `/` has no available size.

```
# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_rayruhsso-lv_root
                      148G  145G     0 100% /
tmpfs                  20G     0   20G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M   41M  411M   9% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_rayruhsso-lv_home
                      270G   54G  202G  22% /home
```

**What I want to solve**
Figuring out what consumed the whole space (I don't want to extend it's size, since it was extended last week from 52G to 148G). The problem is that while tracking down, I found that */root* is consuming much space (128G).

```
# du -sh *
984K
9.3M    bin
39M     boot
4.0K    CdbsMutex
4.0K    cgroup
180K    dev
41M     etc
54G     home
215M    lib
28M     lib64
16K     lost+found
4.0K    media
0       misc
4.0K    mnt
0       net
70M     opt
du: cannot access `proc/4754/task/4754/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/4754/task/4754/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/4754/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/4754/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0       proc
128G    root
17M     sbin
0       selinux
4.0K    srv
0       sys
5.5M    tmp
12G     u01
3.2G    usr
2.0G    var
```

I have checked its sub-directories and found out that the largest file/directory in there is 330M even though `du -sh` displays 128G.

```
#du -sh /root/*
4.0K    /root/anaconda-ks.cfg
4.0K    /root/Desktop
4.0K    /root/Documents
4.0K    /root/Downloads
64K     /root/install.log
12K     /root/install.log.syslog
4.0K    /root/Music
4.0K    /root/Pictures
4.0K    /root/Public
4.0K    /root/Templates
330M    /root/veritas
4.0K    /root/Videos
```

---

```
# cd /root/
# du -sh
128G
```

What's wrong? How to investigate what file is consuming all this space?

I tried to find out the open files but I didn't return any output:

```
lsof | grep deleted
```

Any idea?

**Edit:**

```
# du -h --max-depth=1 /root | sort -h
4.0K    /root/Desktop
4.0K    /root/Documents
4.0K    /root/Downloads
4.0K    /root/.gvfs
4.0K    /root/Music
4.0K    /root/.nautilus
4.0K    /root/Pictures
4.0K    /root/Public
4.0K    /root/Templates
4.0K    /root/Videos
8.0K    /root/.abrt
8.0K    /root/.ssh
12K     /root/.dbus
16K     /root/.gnote
16K     /root/.gnupg
16K     /root/.thumbnails
20K     /root/.cache
28K     /root/.gnome2
64K     /root/.config
144K    /root/.pulse
276K    /root/.gconf
364K    /root/.local
396K    /root/.kde
330M    /root/veritas
128G    /root
```

Comment: Use `du -h --max-depth=1 /root | sort -h` to search for your space consuming stuff.  
At the moment you are skipping the dot-files and dot-directories, due to glob expansion of du -sh /root/*. Please add the modified command and output to your question.

Comment: had a typo in the `sort` command`. Use `sort -h` instead of `sort -u`.

Comment: As I said before, the largest file/directory is 330M.

Comment: I want to send you the output but didn't due to format issue in the comment section.  Anyway, all the files are under 330M

Comment: Can't you edit your question and put the new output there including the command?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This is to inform you that i have included the output along with the given command  in the "OP".  Kindly, find it under "Edit" section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74014/discussion-between-thomas-and-mussa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit forth and back, and a private discussion...

Use `du -h --max-depth=1 /root | sort -h` to search for your space consuming stuff.

At the moment you are skipping the dot-files and dot-directories, due to glob expansion of `du -sh /root/*`.

Now with the results including the dot-files and dot-folders from the edit, it seems the files consuming the space are directly in `/root`.
To get an overview of which files take most space in `/root` use the command as follows.

```
ls -alhSr /root
```

Comment: Hi Thomas! Thanks for giving the time to answer.  I have run that command and the largest file is 396M.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an actual file, it can be a bound file descriptor, that has the storage allocated and never released. Check what processes are using /root and try to restart them one by one, until you release the used storage.

Comment: @Gothrek: If it would have been that filedescriptor, the space would not have been seen with `du` and would only have been reflected by `df`. Also the OP ruled out open filedescriptors.

Comment: Oh, you’re right

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you've issued a delete command and it never ended because the files you were trying to delete were in use by some application?

Try running:

```
/usr/bin/lsof | grep deleted
```

The above command will display all the files which are waiting to be deleted and are being used by a process.

If such files exist, kill their process and check the capacity again.

**Explanation:**

On Linux or Unix systems, deleting a file via rm or through a file manager application will unlink the file from the file system's directory structure; however, if the file is still open (in use by a running process) it will still be accessible to this process and will continue to occupy space on disk. Therefore such processes may need to be restarted before that file's space will be cleared up on the filesystem.

More information on this subject can be found [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2316).

Answer (score 0):

You might also have a look at `ncdu`. It's a lot like treesize and helped me many times to locate large files and directory structures.